# how to visible Cell Border for only right and bottom in Itext Pdf cell

Tags: itext

when I am trying 
`cell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);`

`cell.setBorder(Rectangle.RIGHT);`

It is overlapping bottom border and setting only right border of selected cell

same thing happened in reverse manner with

`cell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);`

`cell.setBorder(Rectangle.RIGHT);`

Does it possible to set bottom and right border of cell together for selected cell ?

Answer (score 32):

In iTextSharp I have used:

```
cell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER | Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER;
```

You could try:

```
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM | Rectangle.RIGHT);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "cell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM | Rectangle.RIGHT);" worked for me in the Java version

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, Rectangle.BOTTOM=2,Rectangle.TOP=1,Rectangle.RIGHT=8,Rectangle.LEFT=4
so for right and bottom,try cell.setBorder(10);,it works for me itext1.3